# Does the subnormal subgroups always form a lattice?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lattice-orders

Let $G$ be a group and $W(G)$ the set of all subnormal subgroups of $G$, partially ordered by inclusion.  My question is if $W(G)$ always forms a lattice (but not necessarily a **sublattice** of $L(G)$). I've heard it holds when $W(G)$ satisfies the maximal condition.

Answer (score 4):

For finite groups $G$ the set $W(G)$ is a sublattice of $L(G)$, since the intersection $A\cap B$ of two subnormal subgroups is again subnormal in $G$, and the join $\langle A,B\rangle$ is again subnormal. For infinite groups, the first part remains true, but the last part need not be true. In fact, Zassenhaus gave an example where the join is not subnormal again. It was recognized that here chain conditions play an important role.

Comment: So does $W(G)$ always form a lattice?

Comment: @CensiLI, since it is a sublattice...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez But it's not always a sublattice of $L(G)$, if no constraint imposed on $G$.

Comment: In Zassenhaus example $W(G)$ is not a lattice, because the join is not subnormal again.  Wielandt showed, that $W(G)$ is a lattice, if $G$ satisfies the maximum condition for all subnormal subgroups, but it is enough to require, that the derived subgroup $G'$ satisfies this (Robinson).

Comment: @DietrichBurde In Zassenhaus example, I think that the join is not subnormal again only violates $W(G)$ to be the sublattice of  $L(G)$, but does not violate $W(G)$ to be a lattice. I don't know how to show that  $W(G)$ in Zassenhaus example is not a lattice. Can you give some hint?

Comment: @CensiLI I thought that every lattice is a sublattice of the subgroup lattice of some group, and that somehow it is the same to say that it is a sublattice of this, or a lattice in itself. But I have to admit that I don't know this really. All results with maximum conditions etc. refer to a sublattice of $L(G)$, so this seems to be more natural to consider.

Comment: @DietrichBurde In fact, the question occurred to me when I was reading lattice theory, but not group theory. And in this point of view it seems to me more natural to consider when $W(G)$ forms a lattice for its own sake. Do you know any book or article that might touch my question? Thank you very much.